# Каким можно взять из массива только одно поле?

Tags: javascript

Существует большой массив, в котором лежит его id в поле id и значение в value. Оба поля содержат цифры. Каким образом я могу получить только цифры из value?

Comment: Ответ был угадан, или всё же надо добавить пример исходного массива в вопрос?))

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array = [{id: 1, value: 100}, {id: 2, value: 200}]

const values = array.map(item => item.value)

console.log(values)
// [100, 200]
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, что нужно.

```
let valuesArray = array.map(item => {
  return item['value']
}
```